# Topic not found error during application load test of a Spring Kafka application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Kafka 1.2.3 in an application developed with Spring Boot 1.5.8. As in many Spring application, I have a test that tries to verify the configuration of Component resolution made by Spring. The test is something similar to the following.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTest {
    @Test
    public void loadContext() throws Exception {}
}
```

The problem is that I am also using Kafka Streams in my application. As far as I know, Kafka Streams requires that **all user topics are created before application's start**.

In fact, I am facing the error during the execution of the above test. There is a dedicated `@Configuration` file including streams definitions.

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyBuilderException: Invalid topology building: stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Topic not found: asd
```

How can I overcome this problem? Am I forced to use *Kafka Embedded* in this simple test? Any workaround?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can upgrade to 1.3.2, you can use a `KafkaAdmin` to create the topic.

[Documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_configuring_topics).

However, it's generally better to use an embedded broker for tests - otherwise your tests will fail if the broker is not available. This is particularly a problem for CI builds.

Comment: So, I need to add an attribute of type `KafkaEmbedded` configured adequately to the test, don't I?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#_junit) about how to use it.